# reset content in an Ionic ios/android application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reset, ionic-framework

in my HTML/CSS/JS web application I have a JS reset button as so:

```
//Reset Button//  
document.forms[0].addEventListener('reset', function() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('resultPrem').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('containerPrem').innerHTML = '';
});
```

I am now testing natively on android and IOS using Ionic and Cordova and this function doesn't work.

What is the correct way reset on Ionic based applications? Should I be using Angular for this?

Im sorry if this a stupid or vague question, I have searched for similar questions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

F

Comment: Can you post your html? And you shud do it in angular way. Check [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example to reset a form in AngularJS:

Controller:

```
$scope.data = { "name": ""};

$scope.reset = function() {
  $scope.data.name = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form" id="form" novalidate>
    <input name="name" ng-model="data.name" placeholder="Name" required/>
    <button class="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</form>
```